# Newton series and Fourier transform, is there an analogy?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis

Fourier expansion for a function:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{- i \omega x}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{i\omega t}f(t)dt \, d\omega$$

Newton series expansion of a function:

$$f(x)=\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \binom {x}m(-1)^{-m} \sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom mk(-1)^{k}f(k)$$

Is there an analogy? Is it possible to make with Newton's series the same things as with Fourier transform? Are the Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform analoguous to difference delta and summation operators?